# Possible to verify the integrity of AIDE itself?

Tags: linux, ids, integrity, software, intrusion

I recently installed the package AIDE (Advanced Intrusion Detection Environment) on my Linux server. This is a web server installed about a year ago. Since no integrity checks have been done before on this server, I can't tell if it is hacked or not.

So, if I install AIDE on this server, considering that it could be under control of an attacker, how I could check if AIDE itself is not compromised by that attacker ? Is there any checksum or hash of the AIDE executable ?

The point is that AIDE could be patched in a way that the attacker could hide its activity from the database creation process.

Comment: What distribution of Linux? There are some systems that can check package file integrity (debsums on Debian-based, yum-verify (I believe) on RHEL/CentOS/Fedora, but those checks could also be compromised.

Comment: The distribution of Linux I use is Ubuntu 18. Since Ubuntu is Debian-based, debsums might worth it I guess ? I could run it from a clean system an compare the result with the current one, but nothing could prevent an attacker to falsify the output making it return the same hash value.